# sudo su while uploading files via PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, remote-access

I have configured PhpStorm for remote server. But, to write a file I need root access so when I am doing it on server I do `sudo su` and PhpStorm throws permission denied error !

Any idea how I can configure PhpStorm to handle this scenario?

Answer (score -6):

If you need to be `root` to write the project files on the server then you're probably doing something wrong.

But you can `ssh` to the server, use `sudo su` to elevate to admin then change the owner and/or rights of the project files to allow the non-privileged user you use with `phpstorm` to upload them.